# Ionic View upload not working

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

I got the ionic view app and am using the 'ionic upload' command to update my code edits. The terminal is giving me a success message, but I'm not seeing the changes when I open the view app.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I tried and it worked. 
after you save your code:

1) Click on your app 
2) Select "CLEAR APP DATA".
3) Select "VIEW APP"

I found the solution here in the ionic forums:

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-upload-not-refreshing-in-ionic-view/20069/15